# What is the difference between these two pieces of code in Lua

Tags: constructor, lua, linked-list

I have been learning about table constructors in Lua from http://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html and I can't understand the difference between these two pieces of code.

```
--between code I've written--    
list = nil
for line in io.lines() do
list = {value=line}
end

l = list
while l do
print(l.value)
end

--and between code they have written--
list = nil
for line in io.lines() do
list = {next=list, value=line}
end

l = list
while l do
print(l.value)
l = l.next
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linked list needs to have a way to get to the next value in the chain.

Without defining `next` in the table you have no next value, indexing `value` does not automatically move `l` to the next value in the list. By not defining `next = list` the last value of `list` is lost and your end result will be only a single value, the last value from your data source.

I changed this example so that is didn't need a file to work with:

Here your code will loop indefinitely printing f each and every time.

```
list = nil
for _,letter in ipairs({'a','b','c','d','e','f'}) do
list = {value=letter} -- we reassign list with new data without preserving the 
                      -- previous data
end

l = list
while l do
print(l.value)        -- the last value of list was {value = 'f'} and it will not
                      -- change in this loop
end
```

Where as the code from the example will go through each value given and complete.

```
list = nil                       -- this marks the end of the list and creates our name
                                 -- we will use to store the list.
for _,letter in ipairs({'a','b','c','d','e','f'}) do
list = {next=list, value=letter} -- the first loop we will create a table where `next` is
                                 -- nil.
                                 -- on the second loop we create a table where `next` is 
                                 -- referencing the table from loop 1 that is stored in list.
                                 -- this will repeat until we have gone through all the
                                 -- letter from our source.
end

l = list
while l do                       
print(l.value)                   -- print our letter.
l = l.next                       -- move on to the table we stored in `next`.
                                 -- this loop ends when we get to the value where 
                                 -- `next` was nil.
                                 -- the table from the first loop of our for loop.
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The for loop of your code does not preserve the previous value of `list`. `list` will end up containing the last line from the input. Your while loop will be infinite.

The for loop of their code saves the previous value of `list` inside the new `list` value. Their while loop changes `l` on each iteration. As a result, it prints a different value each time, and it stops when `l` is `nil`.